# How to connect points with curves in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have some data that I want to connect them with smooth curves. I do not want lines. I am attaching some points below. Instead of lines, I want to have a curve. Can anyone tell me how to do this in gnuplot?

```
-111     -0.07  
 -24      0.09  
  62      0.12  
  69     -0.2  
  86     -0.7  
  99      0.74  
 101     -0.69  
 -45      0.2  
 120.403 -0.5848  
 170     -0.353  
 247.891 -0.105295  
 321      0.0925
```

Answer (score 10):

use the following command, for example,

```
plot "foo" u 1:2 smooth bezier
```

the other options instead of bezier are sbezier, csplines, acsplines. I would just test them for my data and see which one works the best for my purpose.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `smooth` option of `plot`, with  `csplines` :

```
plot "DATA" smooth csplines, "DATA" with points
```

You should not use `bezier` if you want to have the curve going through the points, as it will make a best fit with a minimal number of degrees of freedom.